# как убрать всплывающее окно цветов в vs code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

[image: всплывающее окно цветов]

как убрать всплывающее окно цветов в vs code?

Answer (score 1):

Просто в настройках убрать галочку с настройки `Edit:Color Decorators`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или открыть файл настройки `settings.json` и добавить туда строку

```json
"editor.colorDecorators": false,
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @TuranJafarli на здоровье